# Why are most file extensions 3 characters or less?

Tags: file, operating-system

Most files I see and use end in .something, where the .something is often 3 characters. I know that some file extentions are shorter, like .py or .r, but I have never seen one longer than .exe or .jpg

I know from this [FAQ](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows-vista/File-names-and-file-name-extensions-frequently-asked-questions) that they can be up to 260 characters including the file's name.

Why is the standard 3 characters?

Comment: Extensions longer than 3 characters *do* exist: `.docx`, `.xlsx`, and `.pptx` since MS Office 2007, for instance. There's also `.jpeg` (same as `.jpg`, but with 4 chars instead of 3), `.flac`, `.info`, `.java`, `.json`, `.html`, `.webm`, and more.

Comment: Also, the now very common `.torrent` and one of my favorites, VirtualBox's `.vbox-extpack`

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Because back in the old days of 8-bit micros, when memory and disk space were both hugely more expensive than they are today, most operating systems used a so-called [8.3 file naming system](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/8.3_filename) (8 characters for the filename, and 3 for the extension).

Comment: Thank you for your quick response, I'll read up on the link you provided.